# How to identify namespace in .Net(c#,ASP...)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not an expert in programming. I used to code in c# and ASP.Net. The problem i have to face always is to identify the relevant namespaces for particular keyword. While copying code samples, there occurs errors says like "namespace missing or assembly reference missing". How can i find the namespace for a particular entity?. Is there any simple way?. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The usual way: read books online for class. Or buy Resharper

Comment: Is Resharper automatically resolve the references ?

Comment: It has a trial version. Please evaluate yourself.

Comment: while copying code samples Resharper will automatically try to resolve the namespaces, and will ask you if you want to paste the namespaces for the copied code.

Comment: Thanks  divyanshm. I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to read book no one can provide you a better namespaces directory so my advice to you is that read msdn

also if you copy the codes then just right click like this

[image]

SO visual studio will automatically add this one to your top section of the page

This will help you when you copy paste the code but i recommend you to read namespaces first

Comment: Thanks. But what to do if there is no resolve option ?

Comment: If not, that probably means you didn't reference a needed assembly

Comment: @BinilPXavier: Your best bet then is to google it and look up the MSDN. Most likely this means that the particular assembly reference isn't included in the project. For example, if you look up [`XmlSerializer` in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it notes that it's in the "System.Xml" assembly. In which case, add that specific library/assembly to your project references and try again. If it's a third party assembly, double-check that it's included in your project references.

Comment: Also, a nifty keyboard shortcut to find the namespaces from VS is pressing CTRL + period. Just for those who didn't know :)

Comment: @Chris Sinclair: This is what the answer i needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the keyword and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

It will show you all the related namespaces for the keyword. however if it does not it means you have to add the reference externally.

Add reference externally

Right Click On Project --> Add Reference -->.Net --> select namespace --> Enter.

Or if you have your Own Library in the same project

Right Click On Project --> Add Reference --> Project--> select project --> Enter.

Or if you have any third party dll.

Right Click On Project --> Add Reference --> Browse --> select dll --> Enter.

And than repeat step 1.

Comment: did it solve your problem ?

Comment: Up to an extend. But Reshaper tool will be more helpful if when you don't know the library in which the corresponding class lies.

Answer (score 0):

If you simpy do your mouse over VS will give you option to resolve. More often than not it will solve your problem. Otherwise just copy it to google and write namespace/reference for your desired class and you will get it. You can then go to add reference and add it to your project reference.

Comment: Thanks. Some times i did not get it from google.